# Inserir codigo HTML em iframe direto pelo Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Ola

Eu preciso usar uma variável que contem o meu código HTML para exibir dentro de um `iframe`, mas a minha pagina não exibe. O que pode estar errado ?

Meu código:

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function prepareFrame() {

    var bodycode =
        "<html><head><title>" +
        "Teste</title></head>" +
        "<body>teste</body></html>"                 // ESSE E O HTML
    
    var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
    ifrm.setAttribute("src", bodycode);             // AQUI TENTO INSERIR NO IFRAME
    ifrm.style.width = "500px";
    ifrm.style.height = "500px";
    document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
}
</script>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">prepareFrame();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está fazendo isso:

```
 ifrm.setAttribute("src", bodycode);
```

Ocorre que `src` é o **endereço** do `iframe`, e não o html dele.

Se quer especificar uma string como fonte, tem que modificar o `srcdoc`:

```
 ifrm.setAttribute("srcdoc", bodycode);
```

Veja funcionando:

```html
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function prepareFrame() {

    var bodycode =
        "<html><head><title>" +
        "Teste</title></head>" +
        "<body>teste</body></html>"
    
    var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
    ifrm.setAttribute("srcdoc", bodycode);
    ifrm.style.width = "500px";
    ifrm.style.height = "500px";
    document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
}
</script>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">prepareFrame();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda